# How can I get Jupyter Notebook to import a python file?

Tags: python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook

I have a very simple .py file, displayD3caller.py:

```
def caller():
    print("Here is a print statement from displayD3caller.py")
```

I can import and use the function defined in other files, and from the python shell. However, when I try to import the function in a Jupyter Notebook, it can't find the module:

```
ImportError: No module named 'displayD3caller'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Jupyter Notebook uses any change to the source code of related files, the kernal needs to be restarted. This includes creating a new file.

If you make a new module after Jupyter is already running, you need to restart the kernal before it will find it. From the top menu, select Kernal > Restart. You will need to re-execute any cells whose outputs you depend on.